# Issues applying a scroll bar to a canvas widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm playing around with Tkinter widgets and am trying to apply a scroll bar to a canvas widget but when the program is run it hangs - no error message etc.

Firstly is the general logic to attach a scroll bar ok?

Secondly, the problem seems to be with the `.pack()` method as removing this allows the program to run. As I have used the `.grid()` method else where does this mean I have to use the `.grid()` method for the scroll too? If so how can this be achieved? Any help to get this working would be extremely valued. Thank you in advance for your time.

```
from tkinter import *

x = 10
y = 10
a = 100
b = 100

def change_coord(event):
        global coord
        if event.keysym == 'Up':
            coord[1] -=1
            coord[3] -=3
        if event.keysym == 'Down':
            coord[1] +=1
            coord[3] +=3
        if event.keysym == 'Right':
            coord[0] +=1
            coord[2] +=3
        if event.keysym == 'Left':
            coord[0] -=1
            coord[2] -=3
        canvas1.coords(arc, *coord)


window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")


#canvas scroll bar
scrollbar = Scrollbar(window)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

#canvas and drawing
canvas1=Canvas(window, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, height = 200, width = 400)
canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
coord = [x, y, a, b]
arc = canvas1.create_rectangle(*coord, outline="#fb0", fill="#fb0")

#canvas scrollbar continued
scrollbar.config(command=canvas1.yview)

#captureing keyboard inputs and assigning to function
window.bind_all('<Up>', change_coord)
window.bind_all('<Down>', change_coord)
window.bind_all('<Left>', change_coord)
window.bind_all('<Right>', change_coord)
window.mainloop()
```

Also, I see that when I use the `.pack()` method to place the canvas in the window the program runs, the scroll bar is visible BUT the scroll bar doesn't actually work. Any help with this problem would be very welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Why _are_ you using `grid` instead of `pack` for `canvas1`?

Comment: This code is taken from a larger section of code where all the widgets added have been organized using the grid method.

Comment: From http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm: Warning: Never mix grid and pack in the same master window. BTW, for me, this works somewhat (with `pack` for the canvas). I have a scrollbar and can move the box by clicking the up/down-boxes. The bar itself fills the whole vertical space, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing `pack` and `grid` with two widgets that share the same parent. You can't do that. You need to always use one or the other for all widgets that share the same parent.

Once you solve that problem, the other problem is that you aren't defining what part of the canvas should be viewable. You need to configure the `scrollregion` of the canvas. Most often you simply need to set the scroll region to encompass everything on the canvas. To get the bounding box of everything on the canvas you can use the `bbox` method with the special `"all"` tag:

```
canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"))
```

If you want the scrollable region to be bigger than what has been drawn, specify any size you want as a tuple. You simply specify the coordinates you want to be visible. For example:

```
canvas1.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,10000,10000)
```

Comment: This is great Bryan, thank you. I have added the code you offered, the only issue remaining is that the scroll only becomes functional when the window is minimized to smaller than the rectangle drawing. Even moving the rect down beyond the window limits doesn't make the scroll become functional. What am I doing wrong? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @sw123456: you are doing nothing wrong. This is expected behavior. If you want the scrollbars to control a larger region, tell it what region you want to scroll. For example, if you want the scrollable area to be 10,000 pixels do `canvas1.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,10000,10000))`

Comment: Also, if I were to have more widgets on the window and as i am unable to use the .grid() method to arrange them, if I want to have a scrollable canvas, what is the best way to organise these other widgets as the .pack() method doesn't seem that easy to organise widgets with? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your previous reply! That's great!

Comment: Hi, I know you are probably busy and you have been so helpful already but I wonder if you were able to give my last quandary some thought: ... if I were to have more widgets on the window and as i am unable to use the .grid() method to arrange them, if I want to have a scrollable canvas, what is the best way to organise these other widgets as the .pack() method doesn't seem that easy to organise widgets with? Thanks.

Comment: @sw123456: you are asking a separate question. That question  has been answered several times on this site. I suggest searching for key terms such as canvas, scroll, etc.

Comment: Thanks Bryan for your time. Sam